# WKWebview of iOS9 does not function Websocket and Restful of raw IP adress

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, wkwebview

I am trying use WKWebView instead of UIWebView.
I implemented that the server connection by Websocket and Restful of raw IP adress(e.g wss://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xxx) in javascript  of web page.
I loaded web page with WKWebView in iOS9.
But there are not response from Websocket server and server using Restful in iOS9.iOS10 is OK and UIWebView seems to work.

Raw IP adress can not be use with WKWebView in iOS9?
Dose anyone know of any workaround?

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a VPN on your device? When a Per-App VPN is used in combination with WKWebView it appears that web socket connections are not routed over the VPN. This seems to be an Apple bug, as the UIWebView object has no such problem. Please log with Apple developer support.